# Sum Time Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What I'm trying to accomplish is adding together two time ranges to get a total.
The time ranges are each in a single cell, so one cell has, for example, `7:00 - 12:00`.
Is there a way to add that to the values of other cells that have various time ranges to get a total for all?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get 5 hours from your text cell `7:00 - 12:00`. (If your data is in cell `A1`.)

```
=(VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-",A1,1)))-VALUE(MID(A1,1,SEARCH("-",A1,1)-1)))*24
```

Just set up the adding situation for each of your cells you convert with a similar formula.